# Qt: How to connect to SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, qt

I installed SQLite3 (unpacked to c:/sqlite), created a database (c:/sqlite/mzsales). Now I am trying to show its content in a QTableView.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("mzsales");
bool db_ok = db.open();
```

db_ok is true. Then

```
QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(0, db);
model->setTable("person");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
bool tbl_ok = model->select();
```

tbl_ok is false.

What do I do wrong? How do I connect to db? Thanks!

Comment: SQLite databases are contained in a file; it's not a "server". I'm not sure how it's done in Qt, but you have to specify a full file name somewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got the answer. Here it is:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("C:\\sqlite\\mzsales");
bool db_ok = db.open();
```

No need to connect, just specify the path and all is done.

Comment: Looks like those double slashes `\\` are important. Single slashes in path are not working.